# Вывод даных из БД в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Здраствуйте. У меня вот такая проблема. У меня документ должен быть полностью в php но у меня идёт в перемешку html и php я заганяю в переменную html код и  в конце вывожу его через echo. Но у меня проблема когда я хочу вытащить даные из базы даных и прописать в нужном мне месте, то они почемуто выводяться в самом верху страницы... Почему так ??? что делать что они выводились в тех местах, где нужно?
Помогите пожалуйста... ато срочно нужно сделать....шеф убьет...

вот часть кода который я пишу:

```
$output.="<h4>Список вопросов</h4>";
               $query2="SELECT * FROM main";
               $result2=mysql_query("$query2",$db);
               $myrow2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
               do{
                    $output.="<div class=\"oneQuestion\">
                       <p class=\"name\">"; echo ($myrow2["name"]); $output.=","; echo ($myrow2["city"]); $output.="</p>
                       <p class=\"date\">"; echo ($myrow2["date_voprosa"]);  $output.="</p>
                       <div class=\"clear\"></div>
                       <div class=\"boxTextQuestion\">
                          <p>"; echo ($myrow2["text_voprosa"]); $output.="</p>
                          <div class=\"question_bottom\"></div>
                       </div>
                       <div class=\"doctor_response\">
                          <p>"; echo ($myrow2["text_otveta"]); $output.="</p>
                       </div>
                       <a href=\"#\">Ответ врача</a>
                       <div class=\"clear\"></div>
                    </div>";

                   }
               while($myrow2=mysql_fetch_array($result2));
```

Comment: $myrow2[] тоже в переменную впишите.

Comment: @Vitaliisss, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Maqsood я вписал таким образом :

$output.="<h4>Список вопросов</h4>";
              
      $myrow2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
      $q=$myrow2["name"];
      $w=$myrow2["city"];
      $e=$myrow2["date_voprosa"];
      $d=$myrow2["text_voprosa"];
      $f=$myrow2["text_otveta"];

Потом на местах где нужно выводить прописал echo переменная;
Но это ни чего не изменило..... может ещё как можна ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Советую юзать кавычки не только двойные, но и одинарные. Всё остальное написали выше. Кстати, ты HTML записывал в $output, но тут не видно его вывода.

Кот:

```
<?php
    $output .= "<h4>Список вопросов</h4>";
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM main";
    $result2 = mysql_query("$query2", $db);
    $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
    while($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
        $output .= '<div class="oneQuestion">
                        <p class="name">'.$myrow2["name"].','.$myrow2["city"].'</p>
                        <p class="date">'.$myrow2["date_voprosa"].'</p>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="boxTextQuestion">
                            <p>'.$myrow2["text_voprosa"].'</p>
                            <div class="question_bottom"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="doctor_response">
                            <p>'.$myrow2["text_otveta"].'</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">Ответ врача</a>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>';
        echo $output;
    }       
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Про проблему ТС

```
 $output.="<div class=\"oneQuestion\">
                       <p class=\"name\">"; echo ($myrow2["name"]); $output.=","; echo ($myrow2["city"]); $output.="</p>
```

У тебя весь код такой.

зачем тебе везде **echo**?? все данные заноси в свой **$output** и будет счастье + убери цикл do while и поставь while do, тем самым уберешь

```
$result2 = mysql_query("$query2", $db);
                $myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2); // эту строку, сократишь код и правильно будет работать логика!
```

Все.

ps за глупость и невнимательность ставлю еще и тревогу "работа за автора". тут ведь как "не лепи все в кучу, делай изначально правильно с использованием чего-то одного что знаешь, а не лепи везде красивые, но непонятные слова."

pps и принимай правильные ответы на свои "глупые вопросы"